# Java String replace " with \"

Tags: java, string

I have to replace " with \" in java , I tried

String.replaceall("\"","\\\"")

but it dint work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? I usually find that these are non-questions, about operations that aren't necessary. Who is going to read this escaped quote? Only the Java compiler understands that.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want a literal `\` then you need to escape it in your *regular expression* (the tricky part is that `\` is itself the escape character). You can do something like,

```
String msg = "\"Hello\"";
System.out.println(msg);
msg = msg.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
System.out.println(msg);
```

Output (indicating the changing `"`s) is

```
"Hello"
\"Hello\"
```

Comment: There is no need for a regular expression here, though. For simple text replacements, a `String#replace` will do.

Answer (score 2):

According to the javadoc, `replaceAll` does *regular expression* matching.  That means that the first parameter is treated as a regular expression, and the second parameter also has some characters with special meanings.  See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

The `"` character isn't special in regular expressions, so you don't need to do anything with it.  But for the replacement expression, the backslash is special.  If you have a replacement string and you don't want any of the characters to be treated as special, the easiest way is to use `Matcher.quoteReplacement`:

```
s.replaceAll("\"",Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\""))
```

Also note that this doesn't modify `s` at all.  `replaceAll` *returns* a string and you have to assign it to something (perhaps `s`, perhaps something else).  (I don't know whether you were making that mistake or not, but it's a very common one on StackOverflow.)